# how to get file name to put it for downloader file in webview DownloadListener

Tags: java, android, webview

I have a webview app, and it's for a my local website So..

When I click on a link to download any file, it's download it but with "filename" name just like what I choose it in my code !.

So is there any way to get the file name that downloading to set it as the name of download .

Please edit my code and past it for me because I am a beggener in android programing .

This is my DownloadListener code

Thank's every one ^_^.

```js
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url,String userAgent,String contentDisposition,String type,long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "File Name");
                DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                if (manager != null) {
                    manager.enqueue(request);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "بدأ التحميل ...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try setting the filename in Content-Disposition header? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Something like `request.addRequestHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"filename.txt\"");`

Comment: I have a lot of different files, every page has a different file name, so I want a automatic naming just as original file name.

Answer (score 1):

If it is Get url.the filename will be the end of url.

If it is POST method. the filename will be Agreed in response head.

hope to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I find the code that do what I need, Thank's for every one

I hope to help some one .

```js
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent, String contentDisposition, String mimeType, long contentLength) {
                DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));

                request.setMimeType(mimeType);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                String cookies = CookieManager.getInstance().getCookie(url);
                request.addRequestHeader("cookie", cookies);
                //------------------------COOKIE!!------------------------
                request.addRequestHeader("User-Agent", userAgent);
                request.setDescription("بدأ تحميل الملف...");
                request.setTitle(URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
                request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, URLUtil.guessFileName(url, contentDisposition, mimeType));
                DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
                dm.enqueue(request);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "بدأ تحميل الملف...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
```